# How do I check that no value is null after calling extracting on a list of objects?

Tags: java, assertj

Using AssertJ in a unit test, I want to extract several properties of a custom object from a list of such objects via [`extracting`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#extracting(java.lang.String...)) and check if they are all non-null.

For example, assuming I want to extract `fieldA` and `fieldB` of `MyObject`:

```
import static from org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

List<MyObject> theList = ...; 
assertThat(theList).extracting("fieldA", "fieldB")).isNotNull();
```

I am having trouble figuring out what is being checked.

Is `isNotNull` checking that:

1. the iterable returned by `extracting` is not null?
2. no tuples in the list are null?
3. every value in every tuple is not null?

Comment: Can you also share the exact `assertThat` method. Is it `org.assertj.core.api.FactoryBasedNavigableListAssert.assertThat` or `org.assertj.db.api.Assertions.assertThat` or another one?

Comment: @WLefever added an import statement to clarify.

Comment: That the [iterable returned by `extracting` is not null](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/3.12.2/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractListAssert.html).

Comment: I honestly find your question fair and I tried to make it clearer with my edit, but unfortunately I cannot vote to reopen it. The answer is 1, i.e., it checks that the iterable returned by `extracting` is not null. For the check you'd like to perform, I suggest the following: `assertThat(theList).flatExtracting("fieldA", "fieldB")).doesNotContainNull();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following your example:

```
assertThat(theList).extracting("fieldA", "fieldB").isNotNull();
```

[`isNotNull`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractAssert.html#isNotNull()) only checks that the `Iterable` of tuples returned by [`extracting`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#extracting(java.lang.String...)) is not null.

### `flatExtracting` + `doesNotContainNull`

To check that none of the extracted values are null, you can use [`flatExtracting`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#flatExtracting(java.lang.String...)) and [`doesNotContainNull`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractIterableAssert.html#doesNotContainNull()):

```
assertThat(theList).flatExtracting("fieldA", "fieldB").doesNotContainNull();
```

which yields a message like the following in case of failures:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expecting actual:
  ["value1", "value2", null, "value4"]
not to contain null elements
```

Due to the flattened nature of the solution, there is no indication of which object caused the failure but can be identified by counting the pairs in the displayed `actual`.

### `extracting` + `noneMatch`

The complexity can be increased for clearer error messages:

```
assertThat(theList).extracting("fieldA", "fieldB").noneMatch(tuple -> tuple.toList().contains(null));
```

which yields in case of failure:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: [Extracted: fieldA, fieldB] 
Expecting no elements of:
  [("value1", "value2"), (null, "value4")]
to match given predicate but this element did:
  (null, "value4")
```

### `extracting` + `allSatisfy` + `doesNotContainNull`

Another option for clearer error messages:

```
assertThat(theList).extracting("fieldA", "fieldB").allSatisfy(tuple -> assertThat(tuple.toList()).doesNotContainNull());
```

which yields in case of failure:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: [Extracted: fieldA, fieldB] 
Expecting all elements of:
  [("value1", "value2"), (null, "value4")]
to satisfy given requirements, but these elements did not:

(null, "value4")
error: 
Expecting actual:
  [null, "value4"]
not to contain null elements
```

Comment: This is a good answer as it's the most succinct piece of code that does what the OP wants. However, if they wanted to have more detail in the assertion failure message, such as which element of the list contains a null field, then it would take a lot more code.

Comment: Thanks, I've added possible options in case more detailed messages are required.

Answer (score 2):

When you use AssertJ's `extracting` method followed by `isNotNull()`, it checks if the **list of Objects itself is not null**, not each individual extracted value.

Given your example:

```java
assertThat(theList).extracting("fieldA", "fieldB").isNotNull();
```

Here's what it checks:

1. For every `MyObject` in `theList`, it extracts values of `fieldA` and `fieldB`.
2. The values are combined into an object (for two fields, it'll be a pair).
3. The `isNotNull()` method then asserts that the list of Object itself is not null.

The following code can ensure every value in every object is not null. If any null values are present, the assertion will fail:

```
    import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;
public class test {
     static class MyObject {
            String fieldA;
            String fieldB;

            public MyObject(String fieldA, String fieldB) {
                this.fieldA = fieldA;
                this.fieldB = fieldB;
            }

            // Getter methods for fieldA and fieldB
            public String getFieldA() {
                return fieldA;
            }

            public String getFieldB() {
                return fieldB;
            }
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<MyObject> theList = Arrays.asList(
                new MyObject("valueA1", "valueB1"),
                new MyObject("valueA2", "valueB2"),
                new MyObject("valueA3", "valueB3"),
                new MyObject(null, "valueB4"),  
                new MyObject("valueA5", null)  
            );

            try {
                assertThat(theList).extracting(MyObject::getFieldA).doesNotContainNull();
                System.out.println("Assertion for fieldA passed.");
            } catch (AssertionError e) {
                System.out.println("Assertion for fieldA failed: " + e.getMessage());
            }

            try {
                assertThat(theList).extracting(MyObject::getFieldB).doesNotContainNull();
                System.out.println("Assertion for fieldB passed.");
            } catch (AssertionError e) {
                System.out.println("Assertion for fieldB failed: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
}
```

As you see, this way you can even determine **which element caused a failure**: fieldA or fieldB.

[image]

Comment: `extracting` in conjunction with `isNotNull` DOES NOT check that every value extracted is not null.

Comment: `extracting` returns an [AbstractListAssert](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.assertj/assertj-core/latest/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractListAssert.html). Where is the `toList()` method of that class documented?

Comment: @k314159: I corrected